# Will FreeLibrary (or any other WINAPI) work if I declare it as a sub?

Tags: vb.net, winapi

This is how it should be declared:

```
<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Private Function FreeLibrary(ByVal hModule As IntPtr) as Boolean
End Function
```

Will this also work if I declare it like this?

```
<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Private Sub FreeLibrary(ByVal hModule As IntPtr)
End Sub
```

I have no idea how I can test this. Telling me a way to test it will also be fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under x86 this will be fine for this function. The return value is passed in EAX which is a volatile register under the x86 ABI.

Under x64 this will also be fine. Again the return value is passed in EAX which is also volatile under the x64 ABI.

I don't think that the questions you are asking can readily be tested. You need to understand the calling convention to be able to answer such questions. A static analysis is, in general, necessary.

Frankly though what you are attempting is foolish in my view. I cannot see why you would possibly want to ignore Win32 API return values.